# Authentication with _session

Tags: security, authentication, couchdb

I'm currently trying to use couchdb "session" mechanism. I (ofc) read : http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Security_Features_Overview and http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Session_API .

But I don't manage to log in. So I've wandered a bit and found articles like http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/security.html and http://pierrel.posterous.com/securing-couchdb  as well as a few SO threads.

So, here is what I did:
I created my user db and added an user (totolol:foobar) :

```
{
   "_id": "org.couchdb.user:totolol",
   "_rev": "1-88709660d602783be794f99825849f96",
   "type": "user",
   "name": "totolol",
   "roles": [
       "foo"
   ],
   "password_sha": "c7912a8680385df682ba95db5b994e5e6ca0201d",
   "salt": "1b5889d58de6ba15c51ccf5914f6b58a"
}
```

However, no matter how I try to log in :

```
 curl -vX POST http://org.couchdb.user:totolol:foobar@bachman:8889/_session
 curl -vX POST http://bachman:8889/_session -d 'name=totolol&password=foobar'
 ...
```

I always get the same result, a 401 response with this message :

```
{"error":"unauthorized","reason":"Name or password is incorrect."}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, maybe my config is broken, but I'm stuck. So I'm hoping one of you will show me what to do. :)

Comment: Ok, after talking with the people on #couchdb, it looks like the problem comes from my installation (I have a pretty old version of couchdb), as it works well with them.

Answer (score 0):

With `curl`, use the second example you gave:

```
curl -X POST http://username:password@server:5984/_session -d 'name=totolol&password=foobar'
```

That is definitely the correct procedure. I have confirmed it on CouchDB v1.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

You've confused your user name 'totolol' with the document _id 'org.couchdb.user:totolol'.

It should work fine if you use 'totolol:foo@'.

Answer (score 0):

You created a users DB? CouchDB already has "_users" DB, if you use a different DB for users then you have to change the proper parameter in the local.ini file.